# Prove if an Integer is Divisible by 4, then it can be Written as the Sum of Two Odd Integers.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

So far, I keep showing myself the definitions of even and odd integers over and over but I do not know how to show this without examples. And, well... there are so many.

To prove this, I have..
Taking 2 odd numbers, (2a+1) and (2b+1) where a and b are integers.
(2a+1)+(2b+1)
=2(a+b+1) where (a+b+1)=K => where k is an integer
Thus, 2k is even by definition.
Then, I get lost on how to explain that maybe since it is even it is divisible by 4?

I'm sorry for the dumb question... I am brain dead.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean like $4k=(2k-1)+(2k+1)$?

Comment: Every even number is the sum of two odd numbers.  $2n=(2n-1)+1$.

Comment: You are doing the right thing by looking at the definitions. It might help to reverse your approach, however. Instead of *starting* with two odd numbers, you should be *ending* with two odd numbers. Begin by taking an integer divisible by $4$.

Comment: Hint: Since you are interested in the divisibility of the sum by $4$, try looking at odd numbers and their relationship to $4$. Any odd number is either $4a-1$ or $4b+1$. Combine various types of odd numbers and see how the sum looks with respect to $4$.